# How can I call gmail api's method without authentication everytime?

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-oauth, gmail-api, access-token

I want to use access token instead of authorization. I have get my token and stored it in local storage. Now I am saying, if user has token then do not need of authorization. just call the required method. But it says "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See [https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication"](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication%22). How can I use access token in every Gmail method calling. Like for adding label, getting email messages in my DOM and all this stuff.
In short, I wanna get rid of every time authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally with authorization flow we use something called a refresh token to enable applications to request a new access token when the user is offline or the user returns after being away from the application.   This is not possible with implicit flow.

Implicit flow is defined in [The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2)

> The implicit grant type is used to obtain access tokens (it does not
> support the issuance of refresh tokens) and is optimized for public
> clients known to operate a particular redirection URI.  These clients
> are typically implemented in a browser using a scripting language
> such as JavaScript.

Client side JavaScript uses [implicit flow](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow) there is no other option, the user will need to authorize your application every time they want to use it.

## Official example.

The official Gmail JavaScript quick start will walk you though how to access this api.  The client library handles all the interaction between your application and the authorization server for you so you wont need to worry about where to apply the access token.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Gmail API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Gmail API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      /* exported gapiLoaded */
      /* exported gisLoaded */
      /* exported handleAuthClick */
      /* exported handleSignoutClick */

      // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      const CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
      const API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

      // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
      const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest';

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly';

      let tokenClient;
      let gapiInited = false;
      let gisInited = false;

      document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

      /**
       * Callback after api.js is loaded.
       */
      function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', initializeGapiClient);
      }

      /**
       * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
       * discovery doc to initialize the API.
       */
      async function initializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      /**
       * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
       */
      function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
          client_id: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES,
          callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
      }

      /**
       * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
       */
      function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
          if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            throw (resp);
          }
          document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
          await listLabels();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
          // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
          // when establishing a new session.
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
          // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
          tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
          google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
          gapi.client.setToken('');
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
          document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
          document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
      }

      /**
       * Print all Labels in the authorized user's inbox. If no labels
       * are found an appropriate message is printed.
       */
      async function listLabels() {
        let response;
        try {
          response = await gapi.client.gmail.users.labels.list({
            'userId': 'me',
          });
        } catch (err) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
          return;
        }
        const labels = response.result.labels;
        if (!labels || labels.length == 0) {
          document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No labels found.';
          return;
        }
        // Flatten to string to display
        const output = labels.reduce(
            (str, label) => `${str}${label.name}\n`,
            'Labels:\n');
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
    <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir I am sorry I did not understand. Would you please tell me is this possible to call Gmail Api's method using token??
if yes, then how can I use the access token in my calling function, whenever it makes a call to Gmail API??

Comment: First of I am not a man, so Sir is not needed.     Second you should follow the offical example [Gmail javascript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js)